# Running config wizard after patching

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard, patching

How many and what are the steps that config wizard go through after installing patch....?any one can please generalise this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Configuration Wizard (aka **PSConfig**) does the following steps:

> 1. Initialize SharePoint products and technologies configuration
> 2. Create Configuration database.
> 3. Install help collections
> 4. Secure SharePoint resources
> 5. Register SharePoint Services (install)
> 6. Register SharePoint features (install)
> 7. Provision Central Administration Web application and site
> 8. Register SharePointHealth Analysis rules (installs)
> 9. Create sample data and provision default Web application
> 10. Install application content files
> 11. Finalize SharePoint product and technologies configuration

Source: http://sprickyrick.blogspot.fi/2015/12/psconfig-steps.html

You can configure some of the steps you wish to run by parameters, when you run the Configuration Wizard through PSConfig. Further information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.15).aspx (although it's titled for 2010, it's valid for 2013 as well).